# On Error GoTo statement is still executing although there is no error generated

Tags: vba, excel, error-handling, goto

I have my code below, the strange thing is that the `Errorhandler` procedure is still executing even though there are no errors in the code... What can be the issue?

Running the code without any errorhandlers generates no errors, but still the `msgbox` under `Errorhandler` shows up when I include an error handling statement!

Code

```
Public Sub ExportGraphs(Optional PivotExport As Boolean)
' Exports only graphs on the "Mainwindow" sheet to a new worksheet

    Dim wsh As Worksheet: Set wsh = Sheets.Add
    Dim source_sht As Worksheet: Set source_sht = Sheets("Mainwindow")

    ActiveWindow.Zoom = 70


    On Error GoTo Errorhandler
    With wsh

        If source_sht.OLEObjects("Btn_CurrentTime").Object.Value = True Then
        .Name = source_sht.OLEObjects("CombBox_Instruments").Object.Value & " " & source_sht.OLEObjects("DTPicker_FROM").Object.Value _
                & "-" & source_sht.OLEObjects("DTPicker_TO").Object.Value
        Else
        .Name = source_sht.OLEObjects("CombBox_Instruments").Object.Value & " " & "Max_Possible_To" _
                & "-" & source_sht.OLEObjects("DTPicker_TO").Object.Value

        End If

    End With

    Dim source_chart As ChartObject
    Dim target_rng As Range: Set target_rng = wsh.Range("A1")

    For Each source_chart In source_sht.ChartObjects
        source_chart.CopyPicture xlScreen, xlBitmap
        target_rng.PasteSpecial
        Set target_rng = target_rng.Offset(20, 0)
        Next

    If PivotExport = True Then

    Debug.Print "se"

    End If

Errorhandler:
        MsgBox "An export sheet for this ticker and timeline already exists"

End Sub
```

Comment: Simply put ```Exit Sub``` before ```Errorhandler:``` label. Or add ```If Err.Number <> 0 Then MsgBox ...```. For more infor visit e.g. http://www.cpearson.com/excel/errorhandling.htm

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@dee provided the correct answer.

The `Errorhandler:` is just a place holder.  It does NOT operate like you think.  You are using it like an `If... Then...` statement:

```
If Error Then
   Show MsgBox
Else
    Skip MsgBox
End If
```

As the Errorhandler is just a placeholder and NOT an `If... Then...`, the **code after the placeholder will run regardless of error or no error**.  To rectify this issue, add an `Exit Sub` above the `Errorhandler:` line:

```
Exit Sub

Errorhandler:
    MsgBox "An export sheet for this ticker and timeline already exists"

End Sub
```

Answer (score 4):

In this piece of code, `ErrorHandler:` is what is known as a [line label](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg264568(v=office.15).aspx#sectionSection75).

```
Errorhandler:
        MsgBox "An export sheet for this ticker and timeline already exists"

End Sub
```

Line labels are not executable code, but rather just a marker that can tell other code where to jump to via *any* [GoTo Statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg251368(v=office.15).aspx). Armed with this knowledge, they are obviously not exclusive to error handlers.

The solution here is to use the [Exit Statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg251570(v=office.15).aspx) to return from the `Sub` "early".

```
Exit Sub

Errorhandler:
        MsgBox "An export sheet for this ticker and timeline already exists"

End Sub
```

Others may disagree with me, but I like to build my error handling so that the code *always* stops execution on `Exit Sub`. If the code ends its execution on `End Sub`, something has gone wrong.